# Adding sequence a Column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table: TENDERINFO. There are columns OrderNo, Tender, TenderSequence

I need to update TenderSequence starting from 1 and go on till the number of line items in an OrderNo.

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

So we're going to do row numbering "grouping" by OrderNo. I Can't tell if Tender or TenderSequence can act as a sorting column for your data, so I'll just use OrderNo for that. This shows getting the rownumber using window function row_number():

```
select 
   OrderNo, Tender, TenderSequence,
   row_number() over (partition by OrderNo order by OrderNo asc ) rownumber,
   TenderSequence + row_number() over (partition by OrderNo order by OrderNo asc ) TS_RowNum_ADD
from
   TENDERINFO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as (
   SELECT OrderNo,
          Tender,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY OrderNo ) as rn,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY OrderNo ORDER BY OrderNo ) as rn2
    FROM TENDERINFO
   ) 
UPDATE TENDERINFO T
SET TenderSequence = (SELECT c.rn
                      FROM cte c
                      WHERE c.OrderNo = T.OrderNo
                        AND c.Tender = T.Tender
                     )
```

Not sure which row_number you need.

In your question isn't clear if you can have multiple `Tender` for each `OrderNo`

In that case you may use

```
OVER ( ORDER BY OrderNo, Tender )
```

or

```
OVER ( ORDER BY OrderNo, TenderSequence )
```

Comment: `update x inner join y` isn't valid syntax in Oracle.  It would work perfectly in something like SQL Server.

Comment: @JustinCave yes, i just saw that. I copy the syntaxis from the question instead from the correct answer :( ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to set the table with a sequence, starting from 1 at the smallest OrderNo to number_of_rows to the greatest OrderNo, the following query can achieve it:

```
merge into tenderinfo t 
  using (
    select 
        orderno, 
        rownum rn 
      from (select orderno from TENDERINFO order by orderno)
  ) seq on (seq.orderno = t.orderno )
  when matched then
  update set t.tendersequence = seq.rn ;
```